# Filtering Database Results by User

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm using the below code to pull items from a database. I have 25,000 items with over 300 users. When I use this code it just displays ALL items from EVERY user, rather then the USERID I provided.

```
$UserId is set correctly and displays the right output.
$query is either empty, or contains a search term.
$Pagination contains the pagination number.
$PaginationLimit contains how many items I wanna view per page.

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE user_id='".$UserId."' AND (`item_title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`item_id` LIKE '%".$query."%') ORDER BY date_published DESC LIMIT ".$Pagination." , ".$PaginationLimit;
```

what am I doing wrong?

EDIT #1:
$SQL gets run through $db->query($SQL) which is function that defends me from all that nasty stuff people want to do.

EDIT #2:
I feel like the problem lies within my where statement. if I only include where user_id='$UserID' then it works fine and only displays data from that UserID, when I add AND followed by the %Like% statements it displays data from all userIDs. Am I writing the where statement correctly?

Comment: What does `$SQL` come out as? What are your DB records? Looks like you are open to SQL injections with this.

Comment: Can we see your $query variable, it looks like it's the same for everything so that's why it will select all items

Comment: I've updated my post to fill you in on where $SQL goes. the data is run through a function that protects me from all the nasty stuff. Also, Isaac, the $query is ="" or ="some word or phrase". either way, empty or not, it should display only items from userid? i feel like the first where statement isnt working. If I take away the rest of the where statement and just leave where user_id='' it works fine.

Comment: which data type is user_id  integer or varchar ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you user_id is varchar ... (otherwise youn should remove the single quote around the user_id value)

If the and condition for like regarding both like condition you should use an additional  ()

```
  $SQL = "SELECT * 
        FROM MYTABLE 
        WHERE user_id='".$UserId."'   
        AND ( (`item_title` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
        OR (`item_id` LIKE '%".$query."%') ) 
        ORDER BY date_published 
        DESC LIMIT ".$Pagination." , ".$PaginationLimit;
```

anyway you shoudl not use php var  in SQL you are at risk for sql injection  .. for this you should take a look at your DB driver for binding param

Comment: This was exactly what I need, and thanks for the security tips. the project I'm working on isn;t going public and is more of a learning process for me, so I'll keep in mind all the tips.